# Google custom search: index private documents

Tags: google-custom-search

I'm looking for a solution to index with Google Custom Search some docs (PDF and DOC) which should be private (not visible by public).

Is there any solution to achieve this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Wouldn't it be best to ask this question of Google? It doesn't sound programming-related to me.

Comment: I found out it couldn't be done upon private documents.

Answer (score 1):

With in advanced search in Google you can search by extension.

If the document is private, is it protected by a password or something ? If it's the case, google will not be able to index it.

If you want some google querys tricks, see Jonhy Long tricks from IhackStuff on google.

This is the database:
http://www.hackersforcharity.org/ghdb/